# Java AStar pathfinding - creating one path in multiple segments

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star

I have a grid that I am using A star on which can successfully traverse from one square to another while going around obstacles. However, calculating a long time can cause a certain amount of delay so I thought instead of calculating a 20 grid long path at once why not create the first 5 steps then at that point create the next 5 steps and so on.

My question is that would you not expect the agent to still follow the same route regardless of calculating it 5 steps at a time? At the moment if i change it to go 5 steps at a time then it will start taking different paths and it will quickly crash (the problem for this lies elswhere, it is more the different path I need to figure out).

Below is the path finding code that I found online that I have modified. I'm not sure how useful it will be and there are other parts of code that obviously work with it that I thought would be too much to include. The important part to notice is that the commented out line "//|| shortestPath.getWayPointPath().size() >= 5" for when to judge if a list has been created.

An example below. Normally the 0 would go straight to the wall and around it, but when i try to modify my path finding in any way then the 0 will just go straight to the bottom of the map then right. For any map it seems to make it want to take almost the longest route to the goal and I can't understand why, does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong or a better way of going about this?

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
0    x      1
     x
     x
     x
```

My code for the pathfinding segment is below

```
        if (shortestPath == null) {

         openLocations.add(playerLocation);

            // While the goal has not been found yet
            while (openLocations.size() != 0 || pathFound != true) {
                // get the first node from the open list
                Node current = openLocations.get(0);
                shortestPath = reconstructPath(current);

                // check if current node is the goal node
                if (current.getX() == goalLocation.getX()
                        && current.getY() == goalLocation.getY()
                        //|| shortestPath.getWayPointPath().size() > GameInfo.getPathLength() + GameInfo.getPathCounter()
                        //|| shortestPath.getWayPointPath().size() >= 5
                        ) {
                    shortestPath = reconstructPath(current);
                    pathFound = true;

                    for(Node node: shortestPath.getWayPointPath())
                     totalClosedLocations.add(node);

                    // path has been found
                    break;
                }

                // move current node to the already searched (closed) list
                openLocations.remove(current);
                closedLocations.add(current);

                // set the current nodes neighbours
                current = setNeighbours(current);

                // Now it's time to go through all of the current nodes
                // neighbours and see if they should be the next step
                for (Node neighbor : current.getNeighborList()) {
                    boolean neighborIsBetter;

                    // if we have already searched this Node, don't bother and
                    // continue to the next one
                    if (closedLocations.contains(neighbor)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    boolean found = false;
                    for (Node neighbournode : closedLocations) {
                        if (neighbournode.getX() == neighbor.getX()
                                && neighbournode.getY() == neighbor.getY()) {
                            found = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (found)
                        continue;

                    Node movable = new Node(neighbor.getX(), neighbor.getY(), 
                            neighbor.getCategory(), neighbor.getItype(), neighbor.getId());

                    if (grid[movable.getX()][movable.getY()].size() > 0) {
                        // check to make sure that the square is not of category
                        // 4(immovable object) or category 3(enemy)
                        if ((grid[movable.getX()][movable.getY()].get(0).category == 4 && grid[movable
                                .getX()][movable.getY()].get(0).itype == 0)
                                && grid[movable.getX()][movable.getY()].get(0).obsID != goalLocation.getId()
                                ) {
                            // You cannot move on this square
                            neighbor.setMoveable(false);
                        } else {
                            // You can move on this square. Set parent location
                            // as the players current position.
                            movable.setParent(playerLocation);
                        }
                    }

                    // also just continue if the neighbor is an obstacle
                    if (neighbor.getMoveable()) {

                        // calculate how long the path is if we choose this
                        // neighbor
                        // as the next step in the path
                        float neighborDistanceFromStart = (current
                                .getDistanceFromStart() + getDistanceBetween(
                                current, neighbor));

                        // add neighbor to the open list if it is not there
                        if (!openLocations.contains(neighbor)) {
                            openLocations.add(neighbor);
                            neighborIsBetter = true;
                            // if neighbor is closer to start it could also be
                            // better
                        } else if (neighborDistanceFromStart < current
                                .getDistanceFromStart()) {
                            neighborIsBetter = true;
                        } else {
                            neighborIsBetter = false;
                        }
                        // set neighbors parameters if it is better
                        if (neighborIsBetter) {
                            neighbor.setParent(current);
                            neighbor.setDistanceFromStart(neighborDistanceFromStart);
                            neighbor.setHeuristicDistanceFromGoal(heuristicStar
                                    .getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(
                                            neighbor.getX(), neighbor.getY(),
                                            goalLocation.getX(),
                                            goalLocation.getY()));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            System.out.println("====================");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason beyond obtaining the complete path instead of calculating several stages of the path independently is to guarantee the optimality of the solution. Apart from that, I thing that by obtaining a path of ~200 cell lenght should not experience performance issues. Maybe it is something wrong with your code. I think it would be easier for you to use a search library which provide an implementation for A*. I recommend you to take a look to the [Hipster library](http://hipster4j.org/). The structure of the library is very friendly and keeps separated  the different components from the main logic of the algorithm, which results in a very clean, modular and scalable code. Here is an example code for solving 2D path planning with Hipster:

```
//HERE YOU DEFINE THE SEARCH PROBLEM
// The maze is a 2D map, where each tile defined by 2D coordinates x and y
// can be empty or occupied by an obstacle. We have to define de transition
// function that tells the algorithm which are the available movements from
// a concrete tile point.
SearchProblem p = ProblemBuilder.create()
   .initialState(origin)
   .defineProblemWithoutActions()
   .useTransitionFunction(new StateTransitionFunction<Point>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<Point> successorsOf(Point state) {
         // The transition function returns a collection of transitions.
         // A transition is basically a class Transition with two attributes:
         // source point (from) and destination point (to). Our source point
         // is the current point argument. We have to compute which are the
         // available movements (destination points) from the current point.
         // Class Maze has a helper method that tell us the empty points
         // (where we can move) available:
         //TODO: FILL WITH YOUR CODE GENERATING THE NEIGHBORS, FILTERING
         //THOSE WHICH ARE NOT ACCESIBLE DUE TO OBSTACLES IN YOUR MAP
        return [...]
      }
   })
   .useCostFunction(new CostFunction<Void, Point, Double>() {
      // We know now how to move (transitions) from each tile. We need to define the cost
      // of each movement. A diagonal movement (for example, from (0,0) to (1,1)) is longer
      // than a top/down/left/right movement. Although this is straightforward, if you don't
      // know why, read this http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm.
      // For this purpose, we define a CostFunction that computes the cost of each movement.
      // The CostFunction is an interface with two generic types: S - the state, and T - the cost
      // type. We use Points as states in this problem, and for example doubles to compute the distances:
      @Override
      public Double evaluate(Transition<Void, Point> transition) {
         Point source = transition.getFromState();
         Point destination = transition.getState();
         // The distance from the source to de destination is the euclidean
         // distance between these two points http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance
         return source.distance(destination);
      }
   })
   .build();

//HERE YOU INSTANTIATE THE ALGORITHM AND EXECUTE THE SEARCH
//MazeSearch.printSearch(Hipster.createAStar(p).iterator(), maze);
System.out.println(Hipster.createAStar(p).search(goal));
```

(Full code [here](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/MazeShortestPathExample.java))

The library is licensed Apache2, you can see the examples in the [Github repository](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster) and adapt the transition function to your case. You will find the library very useful for your problem. If you have doubts about how generate the neighbors of a point (filtering those not accesible due to obstacles in the map), take a look to the function `validLocationsFrom(Point)` which is implemented [in the class `Maze2D` of the library](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/development/hipster-core/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/util/examples/maze/Maze2D.java):

```
/**
* Return all neighbor empty points from a specific location point.
* @param loc source point
* @return collection of empty neighbor points.
*/
public Collection<Point> validLocationsFrom(Point loc) {
   Collection<Point> validMoves = new HashSet<Point>();
   // Check for all valid movements
   for (int row = -1; row <= 1; row++) {
      for (int column = -1; column <= 1; column++) {
         try {
            if (isFree(new Point(loc.x + column, loc.y + row))) {
               validMoves.add(new Point(loc.x + column, loc.y + row));
            }
         } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            // Invalid move!
         }
      }
   }
   validMoves.remove(loc);
   return validMoves;
}
```

Also, if you concern about performance, this implementation of A* should find the optimal path in just a few miliseconds. The algorithm generates the nodes used by the search algorithm dinamically, saving a lot of memory in large problems.

I hope my answer helps,